# Programmatically creating a subdomain

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, subdomain

I have a asp.net SaaS application. When a user signs into this application, I would like that a new subdomain is created like, http://clientname.mysite.com ( where www.mysite.com is the default site ) and this gets redirected to a subfolder on my server , which hosts some html pages specific for this site. How can I achieve this functionality, programmatically using the ASP.NET / IIS system.